# Как работает опреатор <|?

Tags: f#

Привет!

Помогите разобраться с работой обратных конвейеров.

Допустим, есть кусок кода:

```
let add x y =
    x + y

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    add 2 <| add 3 <| 4 |> add 7 |> add 8
```

Этот код некорректен, но станет корректен, если убрать `add 2 <|`

Почему сейчас этот код некорректен? Что передаётся в `add 2`?

Comment: А вы попробуйте разобраться на более простом примере

Comment: @FoggyFinder Ну, я понимаю, что происходит здесь: `add 2 <| 2`. Или вы какой пример имели в виду? Без правых операторов?

Comment: да, именно это я и имею ввиду

Comment: мы можем продолжить обсуждение в [F# чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50036/f) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разобрался с помощью [Foggy Finger](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/227049/foggy-finder)

Дело в том, что операторы обратного конвейера тоже **левоассоциативны**, а выражения вычисляются слева направо *независимо от наличия обратного конвейера* - что, к слову, совершенно логично. Т.е. выражение `add 2 <| add 3 <| 4` следует читать не так:

> передать `4` в `add 3`, а затем передать результат в `add 2`

, а так:

> в `add 2` передать `add 3`, затем передать `4` в результат

В данном конкретном примере я пытался передать функцию (значение типа `int -> int`) на место целочисленного аргумента (`int`), что, конечно, является ошибкой. Исправить её можно, например, так: `add 2 <| (add 3 <| 4)` - в этом случае в `add 2` будет передаваться результат сложения, т.е. требуемое целое число.